# How to check if a value exists from user input in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, suse

I want to input values like "2.1", "1.2", "143.22",... So something with this format: number1.number2

So far I have this code to separate number1 and number2.

```
echo -n "Enter value:  "
read answer

left=`echo $answer | awk -F "." '{print $1}'`      # number1
right=`echo $answer | awk -F "." '{print $2}'`     # number2
```

I don't want the user to input something like "1.2.3". How do I check if the user has entered an extra value?

I am thinking of something like this:

```
i=3

while true; do

    if [ -z "`echo $answer | awk -F "." '{print $i}'"]; then
        echo "Invalid input"

    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Will this work?

Comment: Hint: You could check for the number of fields, i.e. `NF`, using `awk`.

Comment: @devnull Will try. But will `awk` be able to distinguish the delimiter `.`?

Comment: Yes. You can specify the delimiter as `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the test using an expression like this:

`if [[ $answer =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
  ...
fi`

HTH, Marcello

Comment: Can you give an explanation for the regular expression

Comment: `^`=`start of string`.....`[0-9]+`=`any number from 1 to 9 and the + means one or more occurences`..... `\.`=`just a dot backslash escaped`..... `$`= `end of string`

Comment: `[0-9]` is a digit (you could use `[[:digit:]]` instead); `+` means "one or more"; `.` is a wildcard, but we need it as a character, so we quote it using the `\`; `^` and `$` means begin and end